# MySQL - Best way to keep database synchronized with multiple clients

Tags: mysql, synchronization, multiple-databases

There are hundreds of clients that will use a windows system in which they manage their own information. That information is sent to a server for analysis (web system).

Both, the clients and the server will have the same database structure. There are some tables that will be updated through the windows clients and other tables through the web system. Few of the tables can be updated in both.

The problem reside that we need to keep synchronized those databases. 
The current approach is to store in a table all the "INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE" statements and once a day update the clients (on open) and the server (on close).

I don't like the current approach as I think it is not very secure (even we are using strong encryption on the data), and I believe there is a better way to do it.

I just migrated to use MariaDB and I was reading this about the Aria Storage Engine:

> Aria can replay almost everything from
>   the log. (Including
>   create/drop/rename/truncate tables).
>   Therefore, you make a backup of Aria
>   by just copying the log.

**Questions:**

- Do you think it is possible to use Aria Logging to solve my problem (how does that is different of the current approach)?
- Does anyone has any experience with a similar case (multi-client synchronization)?
- I just have experience with MyISAM and InnoDB... is there any other Storage Engine that could be better for this case?

**### UPDATE (Jul 2nd)###**

I explored the possibility to use MySQL binlogs and its automatic replication. IMHO, that method is ideal for those cases in which the server data is exactly the same as in the clients. BLACKHOLE storage engine can be used to synchronize only determined tables (which may be very useful). In my case, the server and the clients have the same structure BUT they don't have the same data. In other words, the server contains all client's data, and each client has their own set of data (keeping the same structure).

Trying to apply MySQL's automatic replication, will require to have in the server a database per client, which makes it more complicated.

I think I will stick to the original plan as it gives me the flexibility to easily query the changes per client (until I found a nicer way to do it).

Comment: I found this related (still unanswered) question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218052/two-way-replication-with-mysql-to-sync-instances-of-a-database-app-between-multip

Comment: This tool might be helpful (with command-line support) - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/datacompare/producttour.html

Comment: Thank you, seems interesting, but if I understood correctly, in order to use it, I would have to "open" my mysql connection, which, by security reasons is not desired. Right now we are using SOAP through SSL+Authentication. BTW the server is in Linux.

Comment: I feel that I found the answer. It is called: "MySQL replication using blackhole engine (with binlogs)" and it is described in detail here: http://jroller.com/dschneller/entry/mysql_replication_using_blackhole_engine
It's an automated procedure (much more elegant).